# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, windows

When I start my .net console application from a bat file e.g.  `start myapp.exe`

myapp.exe then tries to write a file to its current directory, although I get a .net runtime error claiming that the file is in use by another application (there is nothing else running)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLmnR.png

Although when I launch it normally with out a batch file e.g. double click on it, it functions fine and outputs the file fine. I thought it might be something to do with privilages, although tried running the batch file as an administrator and I got the same error "File is in use..."

Could anyone shed any light on this?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileSearcher
{
class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirPath = "C:\\";
        FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dirPath); 
        fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;  
        fileWatcher.Filter = "*.exe";    
        // fileWatcher.Filter = "C:\\$Recycle.Bin";   
        //  fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Changed);   
        fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Created);    
        //  fileWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Deleted);  
        //  fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileWatcher_Renamed);    
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;      

        // updated code


        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }



        static void FileWatcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.OldName + " was renamed to " + e.Name);
        }

        static void FileWatcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)

        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name + " was deleted");
        }

        static void FileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

            using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("process.lst", true))
            {
                var data = true;
                fileWriter.Write("C:\\" + e.Name + Environment.NewLine);
            }


        }

        static void FileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code which writes to file.

Comment: Have you tried using [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to determine what other process is using the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like from your batch file that you are sending stdout (1>) to the same file (process.lst) that you are writing to within your application.  **You can do one or the other, not both**.

For example, this application works fine when run by itself:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("process.lst");

    Console.WriteLine("Writing to the file.");

    writer.Write("Testing 1.2.3.4");

    Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
}
```

But, when run from the command line like `myTestApp.exe 1> process.lst` yields the same exception that you have:

`The process cannot access the file 'process.lst' because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: ahh thanks, so I should take out all Console.Writeline references?

Comment: No, keep them.  Just don't redirect stdout in your batch file.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, though I am not redirecting sdout input, I am simply launching the file e.g. start program.exe

Comment: Your image shows the execution of the app being E:\... 1>process.lst.  It's 1>process.lst that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your process after the OnCreated event has finished. Maybe starting a short timer and writing the file when the timer ticks (remember to stop the timer)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/43daf8b2-67ad-4938-98f7-cae3eaa5e63f/

Answer (score 0):

The event that a file has been created is fired immediately, even if the file is not written yet. You should always try to open the file and wait a little bit, when you get the IOException. You can find a solution here: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/jschreuder/archive/2006/07/06/12886.aspx