# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when running a multithreaded maven build

Tags: windows, maven, maven-3

I am having an issue when running a multithreaded maven build. The issue is simple, two threads are trying to access the same file to copy it, transfer it, etc. The issue is that I cannot find a way to tell maven to tell the threads to either *wait* till the file is accessible again or simply solve the problem.

Multithreaded builds are necessary for us so was wondering if this is possible to solve. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added the windows tag to clarify. This is not an issue in linux since the default behavior when opening and using file descriptors is not to lock the file.

Comment: Which plugin produces the problem? May be you need to use an more up-to-date version of the appropriate plugin? May be you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, sorry was not sure what would be the most important details. Multiple plugins fail with this error actually but the most common one I see is flexmojos in addition to any plugin (many) that move/copy files around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077246/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

Answer (score -1):

Drop the target folder manually as Windows might was not able to delete them on its own. Then try mvn clean install

Answer (score -1):

Restart your system it will close all the processes and will resolve the issue.